PHP: Convert HTML to XML for word to read as a document
We currently have a self made PHP class to convert a HTML string into a .doc file using mhtml. This works fine, but our customers would like to be able to export to .docx instead of .doc, which proves to be a bit challenging.
Since .docx is a completely different format, we would likely need to redo most of our code to accomplish this
From my understanding, a .docx file is simply an archive where the word/document.xml contains most of the document.
But since what we have is html, is there a way to convert said html (which mainly contains headers, paragraphs and some tables), to valid xml which word can read, so that I can simply generate the needed xml files from the html and pack it all down in an archive ?

This is likely to get closed as too broad, I suspect. See also Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?

See following project : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

"From my understanding, a .docx file is simply an archive where the word/document.xml contains most of the document" - although technically yes, I wouldn't say "simply".
